# .htaccess redirection from sub folder to current folder with with query parameters

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have `index.php` with query pi which looks like this : `index.php?pi=1`

`.htaccess` code is the following :

```
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/$ index.php?pi=$1 [NC,L]
```

which was supposed to make it look like   `/current_folder/ , /current_folder/2/, /current_folder/3/`

This is causing duplicated issue in Google as : `/current_folder/` 's content is equal to `/current_folder/1/`.

I need to redirect all `/current_folder/1/` to `/current_folder/`, and however leave `/current_folder/2/`, or higher, as they are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved via php solution using if else structure, i.e. when we are on page no.2 view /current folder/ for previous. all good.